# Removing empty line from text file using spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a data file with below format:The file is having 10 columns.
Between every line, there is a space.I have to load this data to data frame after omitting the space and print the distinct value based on last type column:

Sample data file:

```
debo bangalore 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 Yes

debo banaglore 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Yes

abhi Delhi 6 7 9 10 99 99 00 No


Expected o/p:

Yes debo bangalore
No  abhi Delhi




/

/ Defining the data-frame header structure
      val fileHeader = "name address client_add result_code bytes req_method url user hierarchy_code type"
      val schema= StructType(fileHeader.split(" ").map(field=>StructField(field,StringType,true)))
      val textFile=sparkSession.sparkContext.textFile("src/main/resources/student.txt")
      // Converting String RDD to Row RDD for 10 attributes
      val rowRDD = textFile.map(x=>x.split(" "))

      val rowRdd2 = rowRDD.filter(x => (x!= null) && (x.length > 0))
      val rowrdd1=rowRdd2.map(x => Row(x(0), x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4), x(5) , x(6) , x(7) , x(8), x(9)))

      val squidDF = sparkSession.sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowrdd1, schema)
      squidDF.createOrReplaceTempView("data")
```

But the above code is throwing :

```
20/01/20 23:32:50 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at AccumulatorExample$$anonfun$4.apply(AccumulatorExample.scala:50)
    at AccumulatorExample$$anonfun$4.apply(AccumulatorExample.scala:50)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
```

I am not able to come out of the exception.Unable to load this data in data frame.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spark data frame directly with the usage of different parsing modes:

**mode**: By default it is PERMISSIVE.

Possible values are:

**PERMISSIVE**: try to parse all lines: nulls are inserted for missing tokens and extra tokens are ignored.

**DROPMALFORMED**: drop lines that have fewer or more tokens than expected or tokens which do not match the schema.

**FAILFAST**: abort with a RuntimeException if any malformed line is encountered.

File -

```
debo bangalore 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 Yes

debo banaglore 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Yes

abhi Delhi 6 7 9 10 99 99 00 No


alex Newyork
```

Code -

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType,StringType,StructField}

val fileHeader = "name address client_add result_code bytes req_method url user hierarchy_code type"

val columnSize = fileHeader.split(" ").size
val schema= StructType(fileHeader.split(" ").map(field=>StructField(field,StringType,true)))

val csvFilePath = "tmp/data/data_with_empty_lines.txt"

val non_empty_df = spark.read.option("header", "false")
                        .option("delimiter", " ")
                        .option("inferSchema", "true")
                        .schema(schema)
                        .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
                        .csv(csvFilePath)

non_empty_df.show()
```

Result -

```
+----+---------+----------+-----------+-----+----------+---+----+--------------+----+
|name|  address|client_add|result_code|bytes|req_method|url|user|hierarchy_code|type|
+----+---------+----------+-----------+-----+----------+---+----+--------------+----+
|debo|bangalore|         3|          4|    5|         6|  7|   8|             9| Yes|
|debo|banaglore|         4|          5|    6|         7|  8|   9|            10| Yes|
|abhi|    Delhi|         6|          7|    9|        10| 99|  99|            00|  No|
+----+---------+----------+-----------+-----+----------+---+----+--------------+----+
```

For more information on reading the CSV files - https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/read-csv.html

Answer (score 0):

I changed and tested your code as follows:

```
  val fileHeader = 
    "name address client_add result_code bytes req_method url user hierarchy_code type"

  val schema= StructType(fileHeader.split(" ").map(field=>StructField(field,StringType,true)))

  val textFileRDD=sparkSession.sparkContext.textFile("src/main/resources/student.txt")

  val rowRDD = textFileRDD.filter(_.trim.length >0).map(_.split(" ")) // Removing empty lines and creating RDD of "clean" data

  val rowrdd1=rowRdd2.map(x => Row(x(0), x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4), x(5) , x(6) , x(7) , x(8), x(9)))

  val squidDF = sparkSession.sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowrdd1, schema)

  squidDF.show

  squidDF.createOrReplaceTempView("data")
```

A point to remember, Try to filter your data as early as possible in your data pipeline

Comment: I changed the predicate in the `filter` method so now it will consider only the non-empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

@Yayati's solution is good except empty and partial line check.Without that you may run into NPE. Those are fixed here -

File -

```
debo bangalore 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 Yes

debo banaglore 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Yes

abhi Delhi 6 7 9 10 99 99 00 No


alex Newyork
```

Code -

```
    val fileHeader = "name address client_add result_code bytes req_method url user hierarchy_code type"
    val columnSize = fileHeader.split(" ").size
    val schema= StructType(fileHeader.split(" ").map(field=>StructField(field,StringType,true)))
    val textFile=spark.sparkContext.textFile("/Users/msayed2/Documents/temp/test1.txt")

    // Converting String RDD to Row RDD for 10 attributes
    val rowRDD = textFile.filter(_.trim.length > 0).map(x=>x.split(" ")).filter(_.size == columnSize)

    val rowRdd2 = rowRDD.filter(x => (x!= null) && (x.length > 0))
    val rowrdd1=rowRdd2.map(x => Row(x(0), x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4), x(5) , x(6) , x(7) , x(8), x(9)))

    val squidDF = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowrdd1, schema)
    squidDF.show()
```

Result

```
+----+---------+----------+-----------+-----+----------+---+----+--------------+----+
|name|  address|client_add|result_code|bytes|req_method|url|user|hierarchy_code|type|
+----+---------+----------+-----------+-----+----------+---+----+--------------+----+
|debo|bangalore|         3|          4|    5|         6|  7|   8|             9| Yes|
|debo|banaglore|         4|          5|    6|         7|  8|   9|            10| Yes|
|abhi|    Delhi|         6|          7|    9|        10| 99|  99|            00|  No|
+----+---------+----------+-----------+-----+----------+---+----+--------------+----+
```